# How to sync music using other softs rather then iTunes

Tags: itunes, ipod-touch, unix

I use Ubuntu and every time I need to transfer music to my iPod Touch I need to start VirtualBox where I have WindowsXP especially installed for this occasion.

Is there any easier way to transfer/sync/delete musics in my iPod Touch right from Ubuntu?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

There are a bunch of Linux applications that do it.  This question on Ask Unbuntu might help: [Applications To Replace iTunes For iPod Synchronization](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5537/applications-to-replace-itunes-for-ipod-synchronization).

Around my house, my wife and daughter use RhythmBox for loading up their iPod Touches (2G & 3G).